# Unable to get polarity scores from Vader Sentiment Analyzer

Tags: python, csv, nlp, sentiment-analysis, vader

I am trying to add these new words and their corresponding polarity scores from a CSV file into Vader Sentiment Lexicon

[image: New words csv here]

It also reflects in the vadersentiment object when it is updated:

[image]

But as soon as I try to get the polarity scores for the newly added words, it throws an error:

[image]

I am confused as to what is happening even though that the word is present in the Vader dictionary:

[image]

Does anyone know why is it happening?

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to use `pandas` for reading CSV and leveraging `to_dict()` to convert **the dataframe to Dictionary directly**.

I have placed the sample data provided in the question inside vader.csv

**CSV:**

[image]

This is what the dictionary looks like after reading from CSV using `pandas` and converting to the dictionary using `to_dict`.

**DICTIONARY:**

[image]

**SOLUTION CODE**:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_csv('vader.csv', header=None, index_col=0, squeeze=True, skiprows=1).to_dict()
sa_obj = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
sa_obj.lexicon.update(data)
print(sa_obj.lexicon['buffering'])
```

**OUTPUT**:

[image]

Notes:

1. `skiprows=1` is used to skip the headers while converting the dataframe to dictionary